Mac OS Python input event monitoring
This question has come up before, but not in a recent thread, and none of the remedies are working for me. I've created a simple test Python script using trackpad inputs to send MIDI control change information to a mixing console.
I'm getting the following error:
This process is not trusted! Input event monitoring will not be possible until it is added to accessibility clients.
I don't believe Accessibility is used anymore for this - I think it's a holdover from earlier OS. Under "Privacy & Security" I can add applications to a list under "Input Monitoring," and I've added the Python instance, the script itself, and the Terminal. I've even upgraded Python to 3.12 and added that instance. Nothing affects this error.
Does anyone have any advice? Thanks - code copied below.
Dave
import mido
from pynput import mouse, keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener as KeyboardListener
from pynput.mouse import Listener as MouseListener

# Constants
MAX_X_RESOLUTION = 127  # MIDI control change max value

# MIDI setup
outport = mido.open_output('USB Midi Cable', virtual=True)

def send_program_change():
    """Send a MIDI program change message."""
    program_change = mido.Message('program_change', program=1, channel=0)
    outport.send(program_change)

def send_control_change(value):
    """Send a MIDI control change message based on the x position of the trackpad."""
    control_change = mido.Message('control_change', control=1, value=value, channel=0)
    outport.send(control_change)

def on_move(x, y):
    """Handle mouse movement."""
    # Scale the x position to MIDI values (0-127)
    width = 1920
    midi_value = int((x / width) * MAX_X_RESOLUTION)
    send_control_change(midi_value)

def on_press(key):
    """Terminate the program if escape key is pressed."""
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False  # Returning False stops the listener

if __name__ == "__main__":
    send_program_change()

    # Start listening to the keyboard and mouse
    with MouseListener(on_move=on_move) as listener:
        with KeyboardListener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
            listener.join()


JRiggles, thank you for the edit. I'm not sure if that was supposed to be a solution, but I still have the same error.I was originally working in IDLE, the inboard Mac Python editor, and have since exported the code into PyCharm. Pycharm offered me the same dialog I used before, adding PyCharm to the "Input Monitoring" section of my control panel, but that didn't solve the problem. I'm still stuck. Any ideas? Thanks.

As a followup, I replicated the whole process on an older non-Silicone Mac with a simpler user account. Same result. Apple support can't solve this either except to recommend reinstalling the OS, but considering that an entirely different OS failed as well, I don't think that's the solution.
Has anyone successfully overcome this error?
Thanks.

So my takeaway at this point is that there is a fatal error in the Mac implementation of Python which prevents trackpad reporting across the board. There is no solution and no fix. This can't be right. My only recourse at this point is to move to Windows, which I hate to do, but I see no other option. Seriously, no one has ever gotten this to work?

This has been great everyone. Thanks for all the help.
